# Allow INPUT only on one specific port?

Tags: iptables

I want to be able to be able to connect to 1.1.1.1 through port 110 to send email. I currently have the following set

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
```

But it replies with the error `01:37:39 [mta-test] A test email has not been successfully sent to the email address me@me.com: Unable to connect to mail server: Connection timed out(110)`

What do I need to add so 1.1.1.1 can only connect back through port 110? I have tried the following without any luck.

```
iptables -A INPUT tcp --sport 110 -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Your first problem might be that port 110 is for POP3 which is a protocol that does not have anything to do with sending emails (it has to do with retrieving them). Are you looking for port 587? Also, you seem to be missing a `-p` in your second `iptables` command. I assume that's a typo, since otherwise the command would even be accepted (I think).

Answer (score 0):

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT

is the correct syntax to accept **incoming** connections to port 110 from IP 1.1.1.1.

But if you want to use that server to **send** mail then you need to open port 25 (or better: 587).

`iptables(8)` and `iptables-extensions(8)` document the details of the iptables syntax and modules.